# ggplot stat_density2d can't plot contour with tile geoms

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using contours with `stat_density2d` gives error:

```
ggplot(faithful, aes(x = eruptions, y = waiting, fill = ..density..)) + 
  stat_density2d(geom = "tile")
```

> Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type
>   function. Defaulting to continuous. Error in is.finite(x) : default
>   method not implemented for type 'closure'

Using `contour = F` plots without error. What is the issue?

Comment: In the documentation [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_density_2d.html), there's a comment `# If we turn contouring off, we can use use geoms like tiles` immediately before `stat_density_2d(geom = "raster", aes(fill = stat(density)), contour = FALSE)`. It's not clear to me why, though.

Comment: To draw contours, you need breaks, whereas tiles/rasters are continuous. One stat/geom will never plot more than one geom, so if you want colors and lines, make two calls. (Lines second, so they'll be on top.) If you want filled lines, check out the [metR](https://eliocamp.github.io/metR/articles/Visualization-tools.html) package, which does some really cool stuff that way.

Comment: @alistaire can you post as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ggplot, geoms and stats must be paired in each layer added to the plot, so if you want both rasters/tiles and contour lines, you need to make two calls:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(faithful, aes(x = eruptions, y = waiting)) + 
    stat_density2d(aes(fill = ..density..), geom = "raster", contour = FALSE) + 
    stat_density2d()
```

[image]

If you're aiming instead for filled contours, it's really hard without extending ggplot. Happily, that has already been done in the [metR](https://eliocamp.github.io/metR/articles/Visualization-tools.html) package:

```r
ggplot(faithfuld, aes(eruptions, waiting, z = density)) + 
    metR::geom_contour_fill()
```

[image]

Note that I switched to `faithfuld`, which already has the density computed, as `geom_contour_fill`, like `geom_contour`, is designed to work with raster data. It may be possible to get `geom_contour_fill` to do the 2D density estimation for you, but it may be more straightforward to call `MASS::kde2d` (what `stat_density2d` uses) yourself and unpack the results to a data frame suitable for `geom_contour_fill`.